# Linq to SQL authenticate login credentials

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq

I have a localdb in a WPF application and a table for storing a student's credentials, I want to compare the credentials entered by the user to the data in the Student table to see if the student exists. Here is what I have but it isn't quite right.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = tbxUsername.Text;
        char password = tbxPassword.PasswordChar;

        using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
                Student student = (from u in db.Students
                                   where u.Id.Equals(id) &&
                                   u.Password.Equals(password)
                                   select u);

                if(student != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login unsuccessful, no such user!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "it isn't quite right" is too vague.

Comment: @user2324937 Is my answer not clear, not offering an solution? What can I improve to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You are filling `password` with the `PasswordChar`, that seems kind of strange:

```
char password = tbxPassword.PasswordChar;
```

You should create a string called `password` instead of a char and fill it with `tbxPassword.Text`. I woud recommend you to at least insert a hashed password in the database and compare the hash from user input, to the hash in the database. Saving passwords in plaintext is a bad idea.

Use following method, for inserting a password in the database:

```
public static string CreatePasswordHash(string plainpassword)
{
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainpassword);
    data = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(data);
    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
}
```

Following method can be used, to compare the password from user input, with hashed password in database:

```
public static bool IsValidLogin(string id, string password)
{
    password = CreatePasswordHash(password);
    using(db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        Student student = (from u in db.Students
                           where u.Id.Equals(id) &&
                           u.Password.Equals(password)
                           select u);
        if(student != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code at btnSubmit_Click event will be like:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string id = tbxUsername.Text;
    string password = tbxPassword.Text;
    if(IsValidLogin(id, password))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login unsuccessful, no such user!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer! You forgot to dispose `DataClasses1DataContext` in the `IsValidLogin` method as it creates new instance. One more thing - I'm not sure that `CreatePasswordHash(password)` will be correctly translated to SQL, so it might be moved before LINQ query

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Ah thanks, I will modify my answer to your improvements. Edit: Updated:) Edit2: Removed databaseContext from btnSubmit, since that wasn't used anymore.